# How do i make a CSS Sidebar using tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

### CSS Sidebar

**Sidebar does not show up.**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: url("https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/macos-13-macos-ventura-macos-2022-stock-light-5k-retina-2048x1536-8135.jpg") no-repeat;
}

top {
  margin-bottom: 52px;
  position: top;
  display: inherit;
}

content {
  display: table;
}

sidebar {
  display: table-column;
  width: 200px;
}

mainse {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: table-column;
}
```

```html
<content>
  <sidebar></sidebar>
  <mainse>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" disabled checked>
      <span class="slider-switch"></span>
    </label><br><br>
    <label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider-switch"></span>
    </label><br><br>
    <checkbox>
      <input type="checkbox" name="hil">
      <label for="hil" cherad>Hil</label>
    </checkbox><br>
    <button class="primary pri-shadow">
      <label>Label</label>
      <gradient></gradient>
      <tint>
      </tint>
    </button>
    <button class="secondary sec-shadow">
      <label>Label</label>
      <gradient></gradient>
      <tint></tint>
    </button><br><br>
    <button class="primary" disabled>
      <label>Label</label>
      <gradient></gradient>
      <tint></tint>
    </button><br><br>
    <button class="secondary danger">
      <label>Label</label>
      <gradient></gradient>
      <tint></tint>
    </button><br><br>
    <input type="radio" name="rad">
    <label for="rad" cherad>Hil</label>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class="mat-NSVisualEffectMaterialSidebar shadow-primary"></div><br><br><br>
  </mainse>
</content>
```

When I run this, the content does not appear, I just see a blank window.

> For more info and to run:
> View the code: https://replit.com/@GabrielToy1/BigSurcss?v=1

I expected it to show a sidebar and the `mainse` content. What really happened is that everything in the `mainse` did not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [specification for `display:table-column`](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css2/#ref-for-propdef-display%E2%91%A1%E2%91%A7) says

> **Elements with display set to table-column** or table-column-group **are not rendered** (exactly as if they had 'display: none'), but they are useful, because they may have attributes which induce a certain style for the columns they represent.

`display:table-cell` is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Im a noob but I got some suggestions:

1. try to re-write your code from `background:url` to `background-image:url("")`
2. Then maybe you can set `z-index:0` just to make sure the image is not covering anything
3. OR put the image in your html document and try to spawn it in with css background property.

hope it helps.